# When adding Web Reference for WCF to ASP.NET 2.0 there are two additional parameters added

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, iis-7, wcf-binding

I have developed a WCF in ASP.NET 4.5 with a couple of simple methods.  One such method has a return type of bool (written in c#).  When I add this service to my ASP.NET 4.5 web application as a Service Reference, it works as expected in the code behind.  It also works the same way in a .NET 4.5 C# Console application.  Below is the code in the Implementation file for this method:

```
public bool AddADUser(string a, string b)
{
    bool done = false;
    return done;
}
```

When I call it from my programs, it looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var proxy = new ServiceReference1.ADServiceClient();
    proxy.Open();

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.HelloWorld());
        bool success = proxy.AddADUser("testA", "testB");
        Console.WriteLine(success.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    }
    finally
    {
        proxy.Close();
    }
}
```

This is how it works in my ASP.NET 4.5 / C# app, and my C# .NET 4.5 Console App.

When I add this as a "Web Reference" to an existing ASP.NET 2.0 / VB.NET app, it does something different.  The command to call the AddADUser() function is all of a sudden requiring 4 parameters:

```
AddADUser(a As String, b As String, ByRef AddADUserResult As Boolean, ByRef AddADUserResultSpecified As Boolean)
```

Why are these parameters being added -- is this something with VB.NET not allowing this to actually return a boolean, or a web reference not being able to return a boolean, or a problem with this being ASP.NET 2.0 ?

Or do I need to make a custom DataContract?  I have that part left out of my Interface, just relying on defaults.  Do I need to specify XmlSerializer somewhere also to be able to use this?   It appears to actually do what it is supposed to, and I just can't figure out why there are two booleans and which one is the one I want.

Comment: .NET 2.0 doesn't know what WCF is (that's 3.0+).   It's adding the service as an old-style ASMX service.  The differences you see are probably related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page gives a long explanation about it and a weird workaround that I didn't feel like doing:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323097/WCF-ASMX-Interoperability-Removing-the-Annoying-xx

What I wound up doing was adding
    [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]
to my methods and I also added
    [ServiceContract,XmlSerializerFormat]
to my interface attribute and now they act like I would expect.

Reference:  http://www.wenda.io/questions/1191041/result-and-resultspecified-parameters-in-wcf-service.html

Comment: Hmm well even though this fixed my parameter issue, my function always returns false in my .NET 2.0 application but returns the correct value in my .NET 4.5 / Service Reference application.  I guess more research is needed.  (obviously the stub code I put at the top has more logic to determine if it returns true/false).  Blah.

Comment: Just another update -- I tried using [DataContract] and making my own class "public class CompositeType" with a public bool BoolValue { get { return boolValue; } set {boolValue = value;} } and changing my service methods to be of type CompositeType, and setting the DataMember(IsRequired=true) attribute on the BoolValue in the interface and then on the client side I use the CompositeType.BoolValue to get the return value and once again it works on .NET 4.5 but keeps returning false no matter what on the .NET 2.0.  Is there nothing I can do to make this compatible?

Comment: So I figured out what was going on and it has been working the whole time, just the page has been doing double postbacks so its throwing off what i think the results are compared to what they really are.